# Delete a folder in Personal Documents with Batch

Tags: batch-file, directory, delete-file

I do not know why but somehow I can't get it to work.

I need a Batch file that deletes `.Personality` files in a Personal User folder. So if someone else opens the file, it will delete the files in his personal folder.

Path should be `C:\Users\%UserProfile%\Documents\My Games\Wars of Liberty\AI3\`

I have tried some things, but they all say `Path is incorrect`.

Comment: Does 'someone else' have sufficient privileges to access and delete files within another users profile directory?

Comment: Please open a Windows command prompt window, run `set` and look on output list of environment variables with name and value and you see your mistake on looking on environment variable `USERPROFILE`. You can also run `set user` to get displayed just all environment variables starting with `user` in name. See also [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%USERPROFILE%` already includes the `C:\Users\` part, so the path should just be `"%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Wars of Liberty\AI3\"`.

Also, because of the spaces in `My Games` and `Wars of Liberty`, you should put quotes around the path so that batch doesn't break the string into chunks where spaces are.